# Huggingface Transformers ByteLevelBPETokenizer tokenizer not found

Tags: pytorch, conda

I'm trying to run through the (new) tutorial here: https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train, but hit an error trying to load the `ByteLevelBPETokenizer`. I started from an existing conda env and also tried with a totally fresh env, but both give the same error:

`Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'ByteLevelBPETokenizer' from 'tokenizers' (/home/james/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tokenizers/__init__.py)`

Any thoughts as to what might be wrong?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.7

Comment: What happens when you reinstall `tokenizers`?

Comment: Well, just doing `pip install tokenizers` protests with "Requirement already satisfied in /home/james/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.11)"... which is fair enough. I did wonder if this is perhaps the "wrong" tokenizers?

Comment: I just noticed that, if I uninstall/re-install tokenizers, I get: `ERROR: transformers 2.4.1 has requirement tokenizers==0.0.11, but you'll have tokenizers 0.4.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: tokenizers
Successfully installed tokenizers-0.4.2`. Why would I be getting 0.0.11 with the transformers install when 0.4.2 is current? Or are these two different packages?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, turns out the `transformers` installer pulls an older version (0.0.11). So...

```
pip uninstall tokenizers
pip install tokenizers==0.4.2
```

...fixes it.
It does issues a warning: `ERROR: transformers 2.4.1 has requirement tokenizers==0.0.11, but you'll have tokenizers 0.4.2 which is incompatible.`, but this can safely be ignored (this answer came from `@julien-c` at huggingface/tokenizers).